# How to determine whether a table is used to store materialized view logs?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-replication, materialized-views

I have table with created on it materialized view log:

```
create table T1(A number primary key);
create materialized view log on T1 with primary key;
```

Oracle additionally creates two tables for materialized view logs:

```
select TABLE_NAME from USER_TABLES

|T1       |
|MLOG$_T1 |
|RUPD$_T1 |
```

How to determine that `RUPD$_T1` table is a table with the mview logs for `T1`?

I can determine this for `MLOG$_T1`:

```
select MASTER, LOG_TABLE from USER_MVIEW_LOGS

|T1       |MLOG$_T1 |
```

But where to find a reference to the table `RUPD$_T1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its in the SYS base table. i.e.

```
SQL> select  master, log, temp_log from sys.mlog$ where mowner = user and master = 'T1';

MASTER               LOG                  TEMP_LOG
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
T1                   MLOG$_T1             RUPD$_T1
```

Comment: impossible without the use of internal tables?

Comment: @turbanoff its not exposed in the DBA/ALL/USER views. its in a few views like `sys.EXU10SNAPL` `sys.EXU9SNAPL` `sys.KU$_M_VIEW_LOG_VIEW` and the base table `sys.mlog$` only (`select owner, name from dba_dependencies where referenced_name = 'MLOG$' and type = 'VIEW';` will show you all the views that reference the base table, but not all have that column exposed).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 select * from all_mview_logs
```

Comment: it's helpful to explain your answer